# Apache camel component parameter

Tags: java, apache-camel, endpoint

I am writing a custom component for camel. The component depends on a inputstream and an outputstream. I am using camel on different java vms where the process of acquiring these streams differs. Is there a way to pass the two streams to the component/endpoint when creating a route consuming/producing from my endpoint?

Comment: Can you be more precise? In your camel context you can define different routes specifying for each one the from parameter. So what is your case?

Comment: yes, I can use camel just normal. The problem is, that classes which are needed to acquire the streams are not available in a default jvm. So I thought of acquiring the streams then start camel  and pass the streams to my camel component

Comment: Can't you just expose your camel routes as usual and call the "camel entrypoint"  from the acquiring stream process?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean ... How can my component get the Input/Outputstream objects? I want to do s.th. like this but the uri ist just String.
`from("mycomponent:asdf?inputstream=input")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to communicate between different vm-s you could use either vm or seda endpoints.

http://camel.apache.org/vm.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please elaborate on your answer by explaining it further, or perhaps adding an example.